# How to force older packages to install on newer versions of R?

Tags: r

I cannot install `proj4string` into my current version of R (2.15.1):

```
Warning message:
package ‘proj4string’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)
```

I assume this is because 2.15.1 is fairly new and the package just hasn't been updated.  Is there a general mechanism for forcing R to install an older version of a binary package (realizing that there may be bugs that result)?

Comment: download the relevant package (zip, tarball, whatever) from the archives and install it locally (e.g. `install.packages("proj4string_x.y.z.zip",repos=NULL")`

Comment: @BenBolker I was just coming to that conclusion when I realized that `proj4` is the package name not `proj4string`.  Still, care to make your comment an answer in the hopes that it will be useful to others having this problem?

Comment: `devtools::install_version()` is useful too, as is the MRAN "time machine" repo/`checkpoint()` package (I'll come back and make this into an answer at some point, unless someone else wants to ...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(upgraded from a comment)

Download the relevant package (zip, tarball, whatever) from the archives and install it locally, e.g.

```
install.packages("proj4string_x.y.z.zip",repos=NULL)
```

(this is not literal: `x.y.z` represents the package version)

Answer (score 1):

You can use install_version from the package devtools to install a specific package version.

To find the package version:

1. Search for the CRAN page of the package. E.g. for ggmap it is https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=ggmap
2. Check the archived packages. See heading "Downloads" and "Old Sources:"

**Example code for package ggmap**

```
devtools::install_version(  
  "ggmap",
  version = "2.6",
  repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry to bump this post again, but i had the same problem . then i found that I can use the following lines for the package:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")
```

replaced "slowkow/ggrepel" by the package and github repo.

What i noticed that many packages on github will have details to that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Be aware that not all packages are on github

Comment: @RichardScriven, you are right. but for those that are there it worked. Nevertheless, for the remaining ones, I still have a problem with those packages that are not on github. I hope there is a solution that works for those.