# RcmdrPluginPackage Paths

Tags: r

My paths and files are as follows ...

```
E:R/R-2.15.1/library/Rcmdr/
E:R/R-2.15.1/library/RcmdrPlugin.Package/

E:R/R-2.15.1/MyLibrary/RcmdrPlugin.Package.zip
E:R/R-2.15.1/MyLibrary/RcmdrPlugin.Package/
```

where, in the name RcmdrPlugin.Package, I've used the word 'Package' to represent the name of the actual package being used.

The installation is as described above because (i) I'm not an expert at installing packages, (ii) I couldn't do a direct install from Cran because I wanted to put the package onto a USB stick; and, (iii) at work the Cran server is blocked (*sic*).

When I start the package from the GUI the Cmdr opens once and quickly closes (I don't know if this is relevant or normal) and opens again.  Once open, I can operate the package via the Cmdr interface.  It's a very nice package, everything works really well until I want to save the work.  Then I get the following error,

```
Error in obj[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I've been in contact with the people who developed (and are still developing) the package and they cannot reproduce the bug.

I strongly suspect that the problem lies in my 'crappy' install and file configuration, rather than with the package.

Can anyone please help me by suggesting how I would undo what I've done and do it properly in view of the constraints list above?

I appreciate that I can use Remove to get rid of the package but I don't want to start tinkering with something without having a greater understanding of what I'm doing.

Lastly, note that is error has been discussed a number of times on this list but not within this particular context.

Comment: It's a guess, but I suspect you should have your plugin in only a single location. At the moment you have it in both `/library` and `/mylibrary`. Try temporarily removing one of these and see what happens.

Comment: /library temporary removal: cannot find package and hence doesn't open up with libary(RcmdrPlugin.Package).  Whilst /MyLibrary temporary removal, opens package but the same bug appears.

Comment: Ok, another alternative: Remove this package entirely.  Then use `install.packages(package, repos="\location\to\tarball")`. The repos argument allows you to install from any folder (where this folder is a called a library in R speak).  Read about this in `?install.packages`

Comment: what do you mean by location\to\tarball ?  Do you mean \MyLibrary\ or do you mean R's library, viz, \library\ ?  (Apologies if this is obvious).

Comment: It's the location of your package .gz.tar file.  Normally this is the URL to CRAN, but since you can't access this, point it to the folder on your USB stick containing your package. R will then create all the necessary folders in your libraries and install the pacakge.

Comment: removed RcmdrPlugin.Package from MyLibrary and library.  Put the zipped file back into MyLibary and ran, install.packages("RcmdrPlugin.Package_0.10.tar.gz", repos = "E:/R/R-2.15.1/MyLibrary/") but got the following warnings - Warning: unable to access index for repository E:/R/R-2.15.1/MyLibrary/bin/windows/contrib/2.15
Warning message:
package ‘RcmdrPlugin.Package_0.10.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)

Comment: I repeated this procedure with earlier versions of the package, with the same result.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work but I don't know how?  I followed the instructions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820189/how-to-force-older-packages-to-install-on-newer-versions-of-r where I set repos=NULL after I'd put the package into /MyLibrary/

Comment: If you want to answer the question @Andrie, I will close it down.  I don't want to answer my own question without really understanding what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work by following the instructions from here stackoverflow.com/questions/12820189/… where I set repos=NULL after I'd put the package into /MyLibrary/